# Showing startup-messages on QGIS splashscreen

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt4

During the startup of QGIS, there are status messages shown in the lower part of the splashscreen like "restoring loaded plugins".

I am using a startup.py feature from which I would like to inform the user which part of my startup script is executed at the moment.

Is it possible to show this information on the splashscreen?

[image]

Edit1:

As a workaround I managed to use my own splashscreen during startup:

```
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, Qt
import time


template=QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath() + "python/"
app=QgsApplication.instance()
splash_pix = QPixmap(template+'splashscreen.png')

splash = QSplashScreen(splash_pix, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
splash.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
splash.setEnabled(False)

splash.setMask(splash_pix.mask())

progressBar = QProgressBar(splash)
progressBar.setMaximum(10)
progressBar.setGeometry(0, splash_pix.height() - 20, splash_pix.width(), 10)

splash.show()

if QgsApplication.instance().findChild(QSplashScreen):
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("ja", "gridseen", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)
else:
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("nein", "gridseen", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)

splash.showMessage("<h1><font color='white'>Grid Integration-Check!</font></h1>", Qt.AlignBottom | Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.black)

for i in range(1, 11):
    progressBar.setValue(i)
    t = time.time()
    while time.time() < t + 0.1:
        app.processEvents()

time.sleep(2)
splash.close()
```

Therefore I put the splashscreen in my qgis-python folder (for example
https://github.com/webgeodatavore/qgis-splash-screens-birthday/raw/master/resized/qgis_version_2.18.png )

[image]

But this solutions is a bit of a quick and dirty workaround.

Isn't it possible to get access to the splashscreen that's created during the startup of the QGIS app? I tried to get access by using `QgsApplication.instance().findChild(QSplashScreen)` but couldn't get access to it.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/7bd0285dfdef9456a5929a7b7031270ea0ee2601/src/app/main.cpp#L1286

Answer (score 4):

I figured out another solution (QGIS 3.4): [startup.py](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-startup-py-file)

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings,QStandardPaths
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QSplashScreen,QApplication
import os

try:
    s = QSettings()
    s.setValue("PythonPlugins/BufferSelection",True)
except: pass

try:
    widgets= QApplication.allWidgets()
    for wid in widgets:
        if isinstance(wid, QSplashScreen):
            qgisAppDataPath= QStandardPaths.standardLocations(QStandardPaths.AppDataLocation)[0]
            file = os.path.join(qgisAppDataPath,"splash.png")
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                pixmap = QPixmap(file)
                wid.setPixmap(pixmap)
                app.processEvents()
            break
except: pass
```

It also activates my plugin, shows for a short time the original splasher (I guess, that is fair) and then the customized splasher.